# Imaging Processing - Clustering Cells into groups in Fly Embryos Images

Tags: image-processing, scikit-image

I was hoping somebody could help me with an image processing problem. My fly embryos are stained for the cell nuclei in the peripheral nervous system (PNS) - attachment 1. These cell nuclei form clusters in each of the embryonic segments of the fly. My goal is to use these clusters of cell nuclei to label each of the embryonic segments (i.e. one blob or point per segment) - attachment 2.

[PNS Stain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mge1v.png)

[PNS Stain showing blobs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/htqgU.png)

I have had some success by doing Gaussian blur of the labeled nuclei (so that each cluster of nuclei form a blob) and then using adaptive thresholding to identify these "blobs". However, it isn't a very robust method - some clusters don't form or multiple clusters stick together. I'm using scikit-image to do my analysis, here is the relevant portion of my code that I have been using:

> EmbryoBlur = gaussian(Embryo, sigma=(10,5))
>
> ClusteredCells= threshold_adaptive(EmbryoBlur , block_size=151, method="mean")

Does anybody have any other strategies to suggest, so that it robustly forms a single point or blob per cluster of nuclei?

Even if somebody wants to explain a strategy conceptually, I could also trying implement in scikit-image.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a problem that can be solved with **Expectation Maximization (EM)** for a Gaussian mixture model http://www.ics.uci.edu/~smyth/courses/cs274/notes/EMnotes.pdf

Another related approach is **K-Means clustering** (briefly covered in the above link) both of these seek to cluster data by lowering variance within a cluster. For K-means this is usually done with a distance metric, while EM uses probabilities for clustering.

The only downside with both approaches, is you have to know how many clusters there are before you segment the data.Unfortunately I have no knowledge of Scikit, but hopefully this will give you some ideas to look into

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is exactly what you are looking for but I pieced together a script that performs a gaussian blur and then uses a random walker segmentation (similar to watershed) to fill in and segment the nuclei from the background and cell matrix.

You can play with the values to increase or decrease the blur (sigma) and the bottom and top threshold for the segmentation.

I tested it on the PNS Stain image but I had to crop the white border.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from skimage.io import imread
from skimage.segmentation import random_walker
from skimage.color import rgb2grey
from scipy.ndimage.filters import gaussian_filter


#change this to your personal image directory
image = imread(r'C:\Users\YOURNAMEHERE\Desktop\mge1v.png') 
grey_image = rgb2grey(image)

blurred = gaussian_filter(grey_image, sigma=6) #play with sigma for blur amount


#Get markers for random walk
def get_markers(grey_array, bottom_thresh, top_thresh):

    markers = np.zeros_like(grey_array)
    markers[grey_array < bottom_thresh] = 1
    markers[grey_array > top_thresh] = 2

    return markers


#perform Random Walker, fills in positive regions
#play with .1 and .15 to set the thresholds for the labels
segmentation = random_walker(blurred, get_markers(blurred, .1, .125), beta=130, mode='bf')


#Plot images
fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 2, figsize=(12, 11))

ax0, ax1,  ax2, ax3 = axes.ravel()

ax0.imshow(image, cmap=plt.cm.gray, interpolation='nearest')
ax0.set_title("Original")

ax1.imshow(grey_image, cmap=plt.cm.gray, interpolation='nearest')
ax1.set_title("Grey")

ax2.imshow(blurred, cmap=plt.cm.gray)
ax2.set_title("Gaussian Blur")

ax3.imshow(segmentation, cmap=plt.cm.gray)
ax3.set_title("Random Walk Segmented")

for ax in axes.ravel():
    ax.axis('off')

fig.subplots_adjust(left=None, bottom=None, right=None, top=None, wspace=None, hspace=None)


plt.show()
```

## output:

[image: The output of the question image, had to crop out the white]